# Extract Nonetype output

Tags: python, nonetype

I am new to python, this question might be a bit silly, but it has bothered me for a while. 
I am running a program, which one of the function will give a nice formatted table, but it is a Nonetype. So I am not able to use the date. When I launch the function it will show the table in the console like this:

```
In [11]: hs.show(pose, 134)

Dch Dn Dres Da  Ach An Ares Aa  length AHDang BAHang  BAtor weight energy

A   44  HIS  NE2X  998  LIG  O4   2.02  136.0  112.4 -135.1  0.671 -1.069

A   48  ARG  NH1X  998  LIG  O4'  2.04  142.2  105.2  106.7  0.694 -0.929

A   48  ARG  NH2X  998  LIG  O4   2.00  136.9  136.8   76.1  0.694 -0.582

A   48  ARG  NH2X  998  LIG  O3'  2.53  148.2  104.5  180.0  0.694 -0.278

A   48  ARG  NH2X  998  LIG  O4'  2.47  130.8  108.8   43.2  0.694 -0.028

A   48  ARG  NH2X  998  LIG  O5   2.25  130.7  128.7  -48.7  0.694 -0.390

A   61  ASN  ND2X  998  LIG  O6   1.86  168.8  121.7  122.5  0.647 -1.769
```

I am wondering if there is a way that I can just extract this entire section with something similar to *cat* or *awk*??

Comment: The `hs` object contains the data you want, there must be other methods or attributes that you can use to get the data

Comment: I looked through the documentation of the hs function of this program. I didn't see anything that can give similar stuff. Well, I will have to ask the program developers. Thank you for your comment.